# Privacy implications of Android crash reports

Tags: privacy, android, google

To use Google Assistant, you have to agree to let your device automatically submit [Android crash reports](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6135999?p=account_device_info&hl=en&authuser=0&visit_id=1-636404833628351808-2421265353&rd=1) to Google and link them to your account:

> [Information about my device] may include things like whether the screen is on and battery level. The quality of your Wi-Fi or Bluetooth connection, touchscreen and sensor readings, and crash reports can also be included.

What are the privacy implications of this? Could this cause Google to accidentally collect credit card numbers, social security numbers and other sensitive information if they happen to be in memory at the time of the crash?